# How to use Google Tag Manager with Multiple Schema Product reviews using JSON-LD and Variables

Tags: javascript, html, schema, google-tag-manager, json-ld

So I'm using Google Tag Manager to add Schema JSON-LD Product reviews to some pages and I'm stuck and unable to find any resources on the issue.

The issue that I'm having is how can I tell GTM there are multiple elements and they should be repeated in JSON-LD each with their unique values.

The method I'm using to get the values is using CSS selectors which are not unique because on some pages they can appear 20 times and on others 30 times. The variables are obtained by Google GTM.

*Using Google Tag Manager custom HTML on all pages I add*

```
<script>
(function() {

var data = { 

  // THIS APPEARS ONCE.      
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "{{name}}",
  "aggregateRating":
    {
      "@type": "AggregateRating",
      "ratingValue": "{{rating}}",
      "reviewCount": "{{ratingCount}}"
    }

    // THIS BLOCK OF CODE NEEDS TO BE REPEATED EVERYTIME VARIBLE  {{customer}} IS FOUND
    "review": [
      {
        "@type": "Review",
        "author": "{{customer}}",
        "datePublished": "{{date}}",
        "name": "{{desc}}",
        "reviewBody": "{{say}}",
        "reviewRating": {
      "@type": "Rating",
      "ratingValue": "{{customValue}}"        
    }]
  }

  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = "application/ld+json";
  script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
})(document);
</script>
```

Sadly, after testing, I'm unable to get the review part of the JSON-LD to repeat in a uniformed manner. In fact, I can't get more than one review period into the JSON and obviously something wrong with my code and GTM setup.

The variables are then setup in Google TAG manager using DOM Element with CSS selector like so:

[image]

Sometimes the are multiple reviews that appear on the page so I need multiple entries in the JSON, my current code only outputs a max of one.

***The Question, if more than one product review is present on the page, how do I get GTM to add yet another review in the JSON-LD?***

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom JavaScript variables to store arrays of values and then set elements of these arrays as values in JSON-LD.

For example, to get the text of H1 tag you can create custom JavaScript variable with this function:

```
function () {return document.querySelector('h1').innerText;}
```

Let's say you will name this variable h1. Then you can use this variable as {{h1}} in JSON-LD.

JSON-LD code can be stored in custom HTML tag and filled with variables mentioned above.

If you have more then one H1 on the page you can use this variable:

```
function () {return  document.querySelectorAll('h1');}
```

It will return an array of elements and you can loop through this array to get innerText or just look at each element like:

```
{{h1}}[0].innerText
```

Let me show my idea on this blog post example - https://netpeak.net/blog/modify-your-ppc-strategy-to-suit-voice-search/. You can get all H2 headers (or reviews or anything) from the page like this:

```
var allh2 = document.querySelectorAll('h2');
```

In terms of GTM it could be custom JavaScript variable or you can just build one custom HTML tag with JSON-LD. Next you create empty array to store inner text of these headers and push all values as object in JSON-LD notation:

```
var reviews = [];
for(i = 0; i < allh2.length; i ++){ 
  reviews.push({'review':allh2[i].innerText});
}
```

Now you have reviews variable that can be used as a value in JSON-LD markup for "reviews" key.

Comment: The idea is to use GTM to get those values from the HTML.

Comment: Custom JavaScript variables let you do that.

Comment: Please, could you edit your question and include a code demonstration using my code provided, otherwise the answer is low quality and not very helpful, to say the least. I'm looking for an answer in either code or an authoritative answer based on GTM documentation.

Comment: Okay I see where your going with the example but how do you tell JSON to repeat if multiple values are found on the page?

Comment: Custom JavaScript variable is a variable type in GTM and my answer is about using that kind of variables.

Comment: Yep, I know understand a little more where you're going with this. I'm going to edit my question and hopefully it'll give you a better idea what I need it to do.

Comment: I've added the example of function to get a text value from HTML element using CSS selector.

Comment: Hi Again, right I've edited my question and made it more clear. The variable is handled by GTM using a dom element css selector. The variable uses {{}} which is called in the JSON-LD script. So using GTM how do I get it to repeat the review more than once.

Comment: The valuables need to be stored by GTM through. I'm looking for a solution that works with that platform. The method your purposing is a JavaScript method without the use of GTM. I plan to use other triggers and events attached to those variables using GTM at a later date. Unless you can tweak the code I've provided, I've have to keep digging up how to do it with GTM, and most likely using data layers.

Comment: I'm not a JavaScript expert as you can tell. So I think I just need a little more help and explanation on how I can get it to repeat. Possibly a example with a small bit of code that I provided.