# Looping over JSON-ld schema with JS foreach in GTM

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, json-ld

I'm setting up a schema for a restaurant page using JSON-ld in Google Tag Manager. The menu sections update regularly, so would like to loop through this section in the schema using dynamic variable using a data layer variable or javascript variable.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
(function(){


    var data = {
      "@context":"http://schema.org",
      "@type":"Restaurant",
      "url":"https://www.example.com/",
      "name":"Example",
      "hasMenu":{
         "@type":"Menu",
         "name":"Menu",
         "description":{{Menu Description}},
         "hasMenuSection":[{                                 //loop through from here
               "@type":"MenuSection",
               "name":{{Menu Section Name}},
               "description":{{Menu Section Description}},
               "image":{{Menu Section Image}},
         }]
      }
   }}
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'application/ld+json';
    script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify( data );
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
})(document);
</script>
```

My variables are custom JS, however, this also doesn't seem to select the correct elements.
eg {{Menu Section Name}}

```
function () {return  document.querySelectorAll('#menu-section-name');}
```

I was looking at this question [How to use Google Tag Manager with Multiple Schema Product reviews using JSON-LD and Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43708015/how-to-use-google-tag-manager-with-multiple-schema-product-reviews-using-json-ld)
But the answer doesn't quite follow through with the full implementation.
There's also an option here looking at looping through the json data https://nystudio107.com/blog/annotated-json-ld-structured-data-examples but this is in twig and doesn't look at implementation in GTM.

Comment: I think the type you set for the script will stop it executing as Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```js
         "hasMenuSection":
            [...document.querySelectorAll('#menu-section-name')]
              .map( section => {
                "@type": "MenuSection",
                "name": section.querySelectorAll('.section-name').textContent,
                "description": section.querySelectorAll('.section-description').textContent,
                "image": section.querySelectorAll('.section-image').src,
              })
```